# Stick with NetTiers or move to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .nettiers

I have been using NetTiers for a long time in my projects and I have not have issues. But now I am considering taking my development to Visual Studio 2013 and NetTiers doesn't support the platform. I have read a couple stuff on Entity Framework and I think it's a cool tool to use. But My question is this;

NetTiers does a thing I love by generating service classes containing methods from select statements in stored procedures generated by foreign key relationships and Indexes (Unique & non-Unique). Does entity framework do that also? (I mean automatically).

Thanks.

Comment: While this question is several years old. I am currently using nettiers with visual studio 2017 and .net 4.5. so I suspect it had gotten a few updates since this question was asked.

Answer (score 1):

There is an add-on that will do this for you: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762 Database first and code first (reverse engineer) will create all of your mappings and relationships but this tool will let you do what you looking for as far as creating an object that has the CRUD functions built in for you like a manager style class. Although I wouldn't recommend going with that approach when using entity framework. Look into using the repository pattern to do what you are looking to do because ultimately there is no one size fits all when it comes to a data management layer and the repo pattern will let you customize your data management to your needs.